# How to dynamically change the default state ui-router uses?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application that should serve different states based off of some API data.  If my app's state configuration looks like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('order', {
    url: '/order/{serviceId}',
    controller: 'OrderController',
    abstract: true,
    resolve: {
        OrderResolve: function(Order, $stateParams){
            return Order.fetch($stateParams.serviceId);
        }
    }

}).state('order.sharepoint', {
    url: '/sharepoint',
    abstract: true,
    controller: 'SharePointController'

}).state('order.sharepoint.index', {
    url:'',
    controller: 'SharePointServiceController'

}).state('order.sharepoint.setup', {
    url:'',
    controller: 'SharePointSetupController'

}).state('order.sharepoint.confirm', {
    url:'',
    controller: 'SharePointConfirmController'
});
```

Then I want 1 of 2 states to be defaulted to based off of values in the OrderResolve object.  Basically, I use the `resolve` to get API data that tells me whether or not this user has SharePoint service activated.  If the `OrderResolve.hasSharepoint == true` then I want to default to the `order.sharepoint.index` state, but if `OrderResolve.hasSharepoint == false` then I want to default to the `order.sharepoint.setup` state.  The first state shows SharePoint data and the second state is just a form to "setup" Sharepoint services.

Is there a simple way of achieving this type of functionality?

Comment: By default, ui-router seems to select the first state in the $stateProvider which in this case is the `order.sharepoint.index`.. therefore I could just let it load `index` every time and then just re-direct to the `setup` state from the `index` controller if needed.. this just feels hacky

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I have the same problem here, would be nice to post the answer, if you found it

Answer (score 0):

You need a middle state and you already have it. If you remove `abstract: true,` from `order.sharepoint` and always goto that state regardless of your `OrderResolve` resolve value.

Then, in the SharePointController you have access to the `OrderResolve` and you can decided your destination state:

```
// inside SharePointController

if (OrderResolve.hasSharepoint == true){
  $state.go('order.sharepoint.index');
else {
  $state.go('order.sharepoint.setup');
}
```